# unable to predict by LinearRegression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, jupyter

[image]
Should I add `csv` as text in SO question? There's lot more data.

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Income($US)')
plt.scatter(df.year,df.income,color='red',marker='+')
```

[image]

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['year']],df.income)
```

> Output : LinearRegression()

```
reg.predict('10000')
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 reg.predict('10000')
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in
> predict(self, X)
> 236             Returns predicted values.
> 237         """
> --> 238         return self._decision_function(X)
> 239
> 240     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/*base.py in
> *decision_function(self, >X)
> 218         check_is_fitted(self)
> 219
> --> 220         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
> 221         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef*.T,
> 222                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept*
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
> inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
> 61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
> 62             if extra_args <= 0:
> ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
> 64
> 65             # extra_args > 0
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
> check_array(array, >accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd,
>
> > ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
> > 628             # If input is scalar raise error
> > 629             if array.ndim == 0:
> > --> 630                 raise ValueError(
> > 631                     "Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:\narray={}.\n"
> > 632                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
>
> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=10000.
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
> single feature or >array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single
> sample.

I am not sure why I am getting above error. I have income lists of some years. So, I graph it. When I was trying to `predict` a data from `linearRegression` I got the error. I am new to ML(Machine Learning)

How to solve it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to the `predict` method should be a 2d array of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`, which in your case with one feature and one sample would be `(1, 1)`. Therefore add a second dimension for the number of samples: `reg.predict([['10000']])`.